# How to do this without using if?

Tags: nginx

I have a list of blacklisted URLs that I would like to check to see if they are the http_referer for a particular request.  If they are I am trying to set a cookie.  I had tried doing it with the code below:

```
    set $blackListUrls "www.somesite.com,www.anothersite.com,www.yetanother.com";
    location / {
            if($blackListUrls ~* $http_referer){...}

    }
```

But while [reading more](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) about the `if` statement in nginx it sounds like I shouldn't use it.  How can I do what I am talking about above without using an `if` statement?

Also - I have no experience with nginx so if you see a different way I should be checking this  feel free to point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a cookie based on `Referer`, something like this should work:

```
map $http_referer $setcookie {
    default                "";
    http://some.exact.url  "cookiename=cookievalue";
    ~*example\.com         "cookiename=cookievalue";
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        add_header Set-Cookie $setcookie;
        ...
    }
}
```

It will map the $http_referer variable (i.e. `Referer` header) into the $setcookie variable, empty by default (and not empty if referer is listed in the map).  The `add_header` directive is used to add `Set-Cookie` header with the $setcookie value.  The header will not be added if $addcookie evaluates to an empty string.

In the `map` you may use exact strings or regular expressions (with "~" or "~*" prefix).

See here for docs:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

You may also want take a look at nginx [referer module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html).  It is designed to do a whitelisting of referrers though, not blacklisting, and approach using `map` would be easier for a blacklist.

Comment: interesting.  So would your example `~*example\.com` match: `www.example.com`, `ExAmPle.com`, `http://example.com` etc?

Comment: Yes, it will do a match of "example\.com" regular expression, case insensitive. See above for links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you read http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil carefully you'll notice that:

1. if's directly in the server block are OK
2. if's in a location block on the other hand are unsave **unless** they hold only a return or rewrite directive

So to following would actually be perfectly save:

```
server {
  location / {
    set blackListUrls "www.somesite.com,www.anothersite.com,www.yetanother.com";
    if($blackListUrls ~* $http_referer){return 403;}
  } 
}
```

In other words you don't need to get rid of all ifs

Answer (score 0):

Please note: `nginx` has [referer module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html).